# Returning Error Code

Tags: perl, enums

Is it possible to return an error code from a perl script?

I am writing perl script which takes a parameter KEY,

Now to cover up negative scenario,
like
file open failure
Key already exist etc,

I want to return different error code,
like 
enum
{
FILE_OPEN_FAILED,
DUPLICATE_KEY
}

This perl script is called from a C function and depending on the error code I need to generate ALARMS.

Please Help...

Thanks,
V-Anu

Comment: what's up with the exit statement in Perl? Can't exit ERROR_NUMBER; in Perl side and check for it in C program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`exit`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exit.html), [`die`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html) and [`END` blocks](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN%2c-UNITCHECK%2c-CHECK%2c-INIT-and-END) can set the exit code.